# How to use theme colors in Angular-Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm using angular-material and trying to understand how to use the colors/themes. I can't find any good docs/guides on this so I'm kinda lost.

I don't want to create my own theme (yet), I'm just using one of the built-in themes (indigo-pink).

What I'm trying to understand is if I want to apply some color to some html elements, I can just do: `background-color: blue` but I'm pretty sure hard-coding colors like that is not the right way, I should be referencing something in the theme I just don't know how to do that?

I know the Material Design Guidelines have a [bunch of guidance](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/key-colors-tones) on generating the various color shades you should be using from the primary/secondary colors:

[image]

[image]

I assumed there would be an easy way in my css to say "make this div the `Primary Container` color (aka Primary90) based on the current theme". But I have no idea how to do that.

I've seen some examples (in older versions of angular-material, so not sure if this is still relevant) that does stuff like this:

```
color: mat-color(map-get($theme, foreground), secondary-text);
background-color: mat-color(map-get($theme, warn));
```

what are those mat-color things? there are some magic strings in that code `foreground` `secondary-text` `warn`, what other magic strings are there? where are the docs on how to use this stuff (if it's even still the relevant way to do things)?

Comment: btw Those are the material3 guidances and Angular Material still relies on Material 2. The support for M3 is awaited for an upcomming version (v17 or 18 I'd guess).

Comment: That's very helpful info @MatthieuRiegler. Do you know if v16 has any support for Material 2 color concepts? If so are there any docs/articles/blogs/videos on how to use it to apply colors to my application? If not what is the usual way to apply colors? Just YOLO it and define a bunch of my own colors in styles.css to use and forget about the theming in angular-material??

Comment: The official docs have it covered pretty well. Look at the Material 2 specs about palettes [here](https://m2.material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation). Then read about styling components [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components). Among other things, it links back to the theming guide, which covers functions to read different hues from the current palette.